# Vertical Line in Excel Graph Function

Tags: excel

How do I display a vertical line automatically on my graph at a certain point on the x-axis?

- x-axis: years
- y-axis : dollars

So an example might be that I want to draw a line after (A) years, how would I ago about getting a vertical line after A years?

### Chart

Here is a picture of the current chart:

[image: screenshot current chart]

### Data

Here is a picture of the data its pulling from:

[image: screenshot of data source]

- Y axis dollar amount changes depending on the cost of the project
- so theoretically it could be anything from 0 to 1,000,000 or more.
- Most have been within 10k-100k however.

Comment: can you show a screen shot of your data and chart? and what are the input variables that change the Y axis?

Comment: Yeah! Here is a picture of the chart: http://i.imgur.com/snHCYkQ.png

Comment: Here is a picture of the data its pulling from: http://i.imgur.com/JID7wgs.png                    The dollar amount on the Y axis changes depending on the cost of the project, so theoretically it could be anything from 0 to 1,000,000 or more. Most have been within 10k-100k however.

Comment: I don't have Excel on a PC with me right now, but you can use a combo-chart .. I think line and column together and then plot your vertical line as a column chart and use the same row range that you use for your other series. In the column for the vertical line, I am sure you have some formula that sets that value. You can use that value to be high enough to make the vertical line and adjust the chart column width to be as skinny or fat as needed. You will have to play with it a bit to rig it, but you can do it.